# How to make a long table fit in thesis horizontally

Tags: tables

I have a long table in LaTex that I need to fit horizontally in my thesis but I am not sure how to go about it. Currently, my table fits like as shown in the screenshot:[image].

My LaTex code for the table as follows:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Lineage & Max. Temp. & Avg. Temp. & Avg. Pow. Now & Max freq. big & Mode freq. big & Max freq. LITTLE & Mode freq. LITTLE & Max freq. gpu & Mode freq. gpu & Max gpu busy & Mode gpu busy & Mode FPS \\ \hline
        Default & 68 & 58.94 & 7.89 & 1.794 & 1.469 & 1.794 & 1.794 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 54 & 29 & 60 \\ \hline
        HH & 63 & 56.27 & 7.5 & 1.69 & 1.17 & 1.69 & 1.69 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 58 & 32 & 60 \\ \hline
        MH & 60 & 55.58 & 5.59 & 1.17 & 1.17 & 1.053 & 1.053 & 0.338 & 0.26 & 66 & 29 & 60 \\ \hline
        ML & 57 & 53.85 & 4.25 & 0.962 & 0.962 & 0.832 & 0.832 & 0.338 & 0.26 & 53 & 30 & 50 \\ \hline
        LL & 54 & 52.07 & 3.45 & 0.65 & 0.65 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 41 & 28 & 40 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Any idea how I can fit this long table in the page horizontally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea how I can fit this [wide] table in the page horizontally?

As you have provided no information about the document class, the font family, the font size, and the margin widths that are in use, I am forced to assume that the system defaults apply. If this assumption is wrong, please provide the relevant missing information.

The screenshot and code below show that if you're not willing to modify the visual grid pattern, you'll need to switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment *at a minimum*, while also switching to either a `\small` or (better) a `\footnotesize` relative font size -- cf tables 2 and 3. With these modifications, the tables may "fit"; however, the header row looks awful.

Table 4 shows how things can be improved by (a) providing some hierarchical structuring to the header row and (b) omitting all vertical lines and employing fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines.

Can you guess which version I recommend?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

\newcommand{\blobA}{%
\hline
Lineage & Max. Temp. & Avg. Temp. & Avg. Pow. Now & Max freq. big & Mode freq. big & Max freq. LITTLE & Mode freq. LITTLE & Max freq. gpu & Mode freq. gpu & Max gpu busy & Mode gpu busy & Mode FPS \\ 
\hline}

\newcommand\blobB{%
Default & 68 & 58.94 & 7.89 & 1.794 & 1.469 & 1.794 & 1.794 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 54 & 29 & 60 \\ \hline
   HH & 63 & 56.27 & 7.5 & 1.69 & 1.17 & 1.69 & 1.69 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 58 & 32 & 60 \\ \hline
   MH & 60 & 55.58 & 5.59 & 1.17 & 1.17 & 1.053 & 1.053 & 0.338 & 0.26 & 66 & 29 & 60 \\ \hline
   ML & 57 & 53.85 & 4.25 & 0.962 & 0.962 & 0.832 & 0.832 & 0.338 & 0.26 & 53 & 30 & 50 \\ \hline
   LL & 54 & 52.07 & 3.45 & 0.65 & 0.65 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 41 & 28 & 40 \\ 
   \hline}

\newcommand\blobAmod{%
\toprule
Lineage & \mc{Temp} & APN & \mc{freq.\ big} & \mc{freq.\ little} & \mc{freq.\ gpu} & \mc{gpu busy} & MF \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-12}
& max & avg&  & max & mode & max & mode & max & mode & max & mode &  \\ 
\midrule}

\newcommand\blobBmod{%
Default & 68 & 58.94 & 7.89 & 1.794 & 1.469 & 1.794 & 1.794 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 54 & 29 & 60 \\ 
   HH & 63 & 56.27 & 7.5 & 1.69 & 1.17 & 1.69 & 1.69 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 58 & 32 & 60 \\ 
   MH & 60 & 55.58 & 5.59 & 1.17 & 1.17 & 1.053 & 1.053 & 0.338 & 0.26 & 66 & 29 & 60 \\ 
   ML & 57 & 53.85 & 4.25 & 0.962 & 0.962 & 0.832 & 0.832 & 0.338 & 0.26 & 53 & 30 & 50 \\ 
   LL & 54 & 52.07 & 3.45 & 0.65 & 0.65 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 41 & 28 & 40 \\ 
   \bottomrule}

        
        
\begin{document}

% OP's code ('tabular')
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabular}{|l| *{12}{l|}}
\blobA\blobB
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

% tabularx, \small
\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l| *{12}{L|}}
\blobA\blobB
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 

% tabularx, \footnotesize
\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l| *{12}{L|}}
\blobA\blobB
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 

% tabular, \small, organize header row ("\blobAmod");
% no vert. lines and fewer but well-spaced horiz. lines
% ("\blobBmod").
\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{11}{L} l @{}}
\blobAmod\blobBmod
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{13}{@{}l}{\footnotesize APN: Avg. Pow. Now; MF: Mode FPS.}

\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I chose the 3rd table. It fit perfectly. Thank you. :) :) :)

Answer (score 4):

Another idea is rotate column headers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating, makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \small
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Mode freq.}    % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {l    X[c] 
                             X[c, si={table-format=2.2}]
                             X[c, si={table-format=1.2}]
                        *{6}{X[c, si={table-format=1.3}]}
                        *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]} },
             colsep  = 3pt,
             row{1}  = {guard, c, cmd=\rothead}
             }
Lineage & Max. Temp. & Avg. Temp. & Avg. Pow. Now & Max freq. big & Mode freq. big & Max freq. LITTLE & Mode freq. LITTLE & Max freq. gpu & Mode freq. gpu & Max gpu busy & Mode gpu busy & Mode FPS \\  
Default & 68 & 58.94 & 7.89 & 1.794 & 1.469 & 1.794 & 1.794 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 54 & 29 & 60 \\  
HH      & 63 & 56.27 & 7.5  & 1.69  & 1.17  & 1.69  & 1.69  & 0.455 & 0.26 & 58 & 32 & 60 \\  
MH      & 60 & 55.58 & 5.59 & 1.17  & 1.17  & 1.053 & 1.053 & 0.338 & 0.26 & 66 & 29 & 60 \\  
ML      & 57 & 53.85 & 4.25 & 0.962 & 0.962 & 0.832 & 0.832 & 0.338 & 0.26 & 53 & 30 & 50 \\  
LL      & 54 & 52.07 & 3.45 & 0.65  & 0.65  & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.26 & 41 & 28 & 40 \\  
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]